# Can a class implementing Database.Batchable also implement Schedulable and schedule itself to run?

Tags: schedulebatch

Rather than creating a separate Schedulable class which executes my Batchable class (which in turn has a callout), shouldn't I be able to have my Batchable class also implement the Schedulable interface and in the execute(SchedulableContext) method, new up the same Batchable class and pass it to the Database.executeBatch method?

This works fine when I execute the schedule from the dev console like so:

```
Batch_APNEmail batchApex = new Batch_APNEmail();
batchApex.execute(null);
```

But when I create a scheduled job through the Salesforce web interface and configure it to execute daily at 9am, it throws the exception:

> System.CalloutException: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.

My schedulable/batchable class declaration looks like this:

```
global class Batch_APNEmail implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable
```

My Scheduleable execute method within the schedulable/batchable class looks like this:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
    Batch_APNEmail batchAPN = new Batch_APNEmail();
    Database.executeBatch(batchAPN, 1);
}
```

Here's a unit test which runs successfully:

```
@isTest static void test_Schedule(){
    Create_APNs();

    // Setup the mock callouts with static resources
    Setup_Static_Resources();

    Test.startTest();
        Batch_APNEmail batchApex = new Batch_APNEmail();
        batchApex.execute(null);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Verify the callouts were made
    List<Academic_Progress_Notification__c> apns = [SELECT Emailed_Student__c FROM Academic_Progress_Notification__c];
    for (Academic_Progress_Notification__c apn : apns){
        System.assertEquals(apn.Emailed_Student__c != null, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In general, you can combine as many interfaces as you want within a single class, so long as they are all compatible. Using the scheduable and batchable interface within the same class just means you have to implement all four methods. Your class will start off like:

```
public class x implements Database.Batchable<Object>, Database.AllowCallouts, Scheduable {
```

As an aside, you could also use Scheduable to call a future method, which may be simpler if you need just one callout (or, less than the 10 limit). In which case:

```
@future(callout=true) public static void doCallout() {
```

Comment: From the looks of his question he is doing exactly as you state in your answer yet he is getting issues. Do you see positive results with a callout using your methods? If so then the OP has something else going on and will need to post more code.

Comment: True enough. I just noticed that after you pointed it out. It's hard to keep an entire message in context on a phone. I'd guess that they're trying to callout in the constructor, since that's the only opportunity where they'd be able to generate this error in their Scheduable execute.

Comment: I'm not using @future because the callout is made from within the batch execute method.  Also, recall that no such callout error is thrown when executing the schedule from the developer console.

Comment: It works in Execute Anonymous because you're not in a Schedulable context. That's much like comparing apples and oranges. Try writing a test method for your class. Can you get the test to pass?

Comment: It passes when executing from a unit test as well.  I'm not certain I'm executing it properly from within my test though.  I'm executing it the same way as I described in my anonymous apex example above.
How can I build a test that executes the schedule immediately and runs the batch apex immediately without passing null to the scheduleable execute method?  Or have I done it correctly?

Comment: No, you have to use Test.startTest and Test.stopTest. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm for information on a proper test.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the unit test you described.  It runs successfully.

Comment: That's an incorrect test. You must schedule the class and let it execute naturally. Do not call execute(null), because then it is being called in the wrong context.

Comment: I think you're describing an integration test.  For the purposes of a unit test, wouldn't it need to execute immediately and not (possibly) an hour later?

In the dev console when I execute the following it runs fine:
String cronExp = '0 0 0-23 * * ?';
String tmpId = System.schedule('PASS_Notifications', cronExp, new Batch_APNEmail());

But, scheduling it from the web interface it fails with the error described above.  I suspect that Salesforce is simply checking if a callout is made from the class implementing the Schedulable interface prior to executing the schedule scheduled in this way.

Comment: The point of test.stoptest is to execute any asynchronous code that's been called. Future, scheduled, and batch code all fall into this category. Without this context switch, you can't prove that code is working in the intended fashion. For example, the scheduablecontext value being null isn't a real world use case. All scheduled executions have a Scheduable context.

Comment: Also, as I've pointed out, certain calls aren't allowed in certain contexts. The only way to catch this problem is to unit test or live test. Since the scheduler is failing in the real world, the unit test isn't matching the behavior.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I've  question related to this. If my class implements Schedulable as well as Database.Stateful, can my class retain the values of its instance variables in between scheduled executions?

Comment: @Shiva If you want a more comprehensive answer, consider asking a new question. But, as far as I can fit in a comment, Database.Stateful only works with Database.Batchable. If you need to store data for Queueable or Schedulable, you have to make other arrangements. Schedulable could use abortJob/schedule combo to store new data, while Queuable can use enqueueJob. Otherwise, you can store the data in a record somewhere.